# Alternative symbol for dot/period/full stop that will work at the end of a folder name?

Tags: unicode, symbols, files-folders, character-map

I'm looking for an alternative period sign that will work at the end of a folder name.
It's not super important, but in my music organizing there is an album title that is stylized with a period at the end and it can't show this in Windows. This happens for other symbols too, like question marks, colons, etc., but I have found alternatives for those:

```
꞉ Ɂ ⁄
```

...But I've yet to find a replacement for the standard dot. "."

Any suggestions?

(Windows 10)

Comment: [“.” U+002E Full Stop Unicode Character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+002E)?

Comment: That's the normal one, but the one dot leader “․” (U+2024) on the bottom of the page you linked seems to do the trick. Thanks! @DavidPostill

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### I'm looking for an alternative period sign that will work at the end of a folder name

You can use one of:

- Full Stop - [Unicode Character “.” (U+002E)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+002E), or
- One Dot Leader - [Unicode Character “․” (U+2024)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2024)

One (or both) of these should work at the end of a folder name (you didn't specify your Operating system).